# ERROR DE ARCHIVO EXTENSION ,BACPAC SQLSERVER 2019

Tags: sql-server-2019

estoy tratando de hacer una copia de mi base de datos que esta en sql server 2019, deseo importarla a Azure a través de Data Factory, la base de datos debe tener una extension .bacpac, entro al explorador de MSQLSERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO, sigo el paso inicial que es ir  a la base de datos y le doy clic derecho Tasks.....ExportData Tier Aplicaccion.... sigo los pasos del asistente next..next me dice que completo la operacion debido a un fallo en la operacion veo el resumen y falto por completar 3 archivos exporting Base de Datos, Validacion esquema y alidacion modelo de esquema para paquete de datos miro el detalle del error:
ne or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[RECONTRUIRINDICES]: Procedure: [dbo].[RECONTRUIRINDICES] has an unresolved reference to object [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[RECONTRUIRINDICES]: Procedure: [dbo].[RECONTRUIRINDICES] has an unresolved reference to object [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases].[name]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Gracias Por su ayuda tengo dias buscando el problema y Msdn me habla de todo menos de eso

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo en atender la solicitud,  pues mira solo necesito importar una base de datos desde sqlserver 2019 con extensión .bacpac pero al hacerlo con la opción  lTasks.....ExportData Tier Aplicación....me aparece el error que el proceso no es completado por problemas de validación de esquema arrojando el siquiente error Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[RECONTRUIRINDICES]: Procedure: [dbo].[RECONTRUIRINDICES] has an unresolved reference to object [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases].[name]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.